# Создание моста Centos KVM

Tags: linux, centos, сеть, kvm

Есть машина сервиса online.net, на ней Centos 7, нужно поднять две виртуалки, поднял одну Centos 6.6 и столкнулся с проблемой интерфейса (моста).

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 195.154.200.167  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 195.154.200.255
        inet6 fe80::d6ae:52ff:fecf:3344  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d4:ae:52:cf:33:44  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9607  bytes 1594014 (1.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 24  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4938  bytes 2677884 (2.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

В него так же заходят ещё два айпи

```
eth0:0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 195.154.36.34  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 195.154.36.34
        ether d4:ae:52:cf:33:44  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

В данном интерфейсе не активирован виртуальный MAC-адрес
Настройка второго интерфейса с активированным MAC-адресом

```
DEVICE="eth0:1"
HWADDR=52:54:00:00:40:85 # виртуальный мак
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE=br0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

И мост над ним

```
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR="195.154.36.32"
NETMASK="255.255.255.255"
ONBOOT=yes
DELAY=0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

Во всех своих изысканиях пришёл к отключению firewalld, установки iptables b прочих шаманств по линкам

- http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking

И прочих, кстати, [команда приводимая здесь](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide/sect-Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide-Network_Configuration-Network_Configuration-Bridged_networking_with_libvirt.html) приводит к ошибке

```
[root@wtcard ~]# virsh iface-bridge eth0:1 br0
error: failed to get interface 'eth0:1'
error: internal error: couldn't find interface named 'eth0:1': unspecified error - errors in loading some config files
```

Подскажите в каком направлении я двигаюсь не так ?

Comment: первые два неправильных направления связаны с `network aliases` и `ifconfig`. `aliases` уже лет пять или десять просто не существует, а `ifconfig` уже пятнадцать лет как работает некорректно: следует использовать программу `ip`. третье неправильное (насколько я понимаю) направеление — это какие-то «виртуальные маки».

Comment: к сожалению, не нашёл толкового краткого руководства, потому приведу просто поисковую строку: *kvm bridge multiple ip*

Answer (score 1):

[Вот вам ссылочка](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=kvm&f=1) перейдите и там во втором пункте расписано как сделать мост для KVM. И вообще классный сайт для centos